# Caller Display Possible in Windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to make a contact manager as I think the Windows 7 Phone is lacking a bit. I got to thinking though about a potential problem.

Right now if someone calls me and I have them in my contacts list their name will show up and I will know who they are.

I am wondering if I will be able to hook up the caller id to check out my contact list as well to see if the phone number exists in the phone.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: It's not. However, you can use `SavePhoneNumberTask` to add number to contact list.

Comment: So your saying I will have to save the phone number in "People's Hub" as well as my contact manager?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm saying.

Comment: Thought it would be a one way sync though right? If all of sudden the contact was deleted in my program I can't go an do delete it in the people hub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible neither in Windows Phone 7.x nor in Windows Phone 8. You cannot write service apps  i.e. the applications that stay in the background and watch for some system events, nor replace built in applications or responses.

Sadly, this is a great limitation currently and I hope it will be overturned in the next version of OS.

Comment: Hmm that sucks. I guess going to have it duplicated some how in the People area so people don't lose that functionality if they choose to use my contact manager.

Comment: That is the best way to do it - copy and extend built-in apps :/